# How to add loading screen to React router ambiguous matches?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

**App Component**:

```
function App() {
  const links = ["page-1", "page-2", "page-3"].map(item => {
    return (
      <Link key={item} to={"/" + item}>
        {item}
      </Link>
    );
  });

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <>
        <nav>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          {links}
        </nav>

        <div className="app">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/:pagename" component={Page} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

**Page Component**:

```
Page extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { loading: true };

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ loading: false });
    }, 500);
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.loading ? (
      <h1>Loading...</h1>
    ) : (
      <h1>{this.props.match.params.pagename}</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

**Problem**:

I want a loading screen when React switches between pages. There's no problem when it starts at "/". However, when switching between say "/page-1" and "/page-2" it doesn't show a loading screen despite the `setTimeOut()` function.

It works when I switch back to "/" first. A.k.a. from "/page-1" to "/" and then to "/page-2". How do I make the loading screen show when switching to "/page-2" from "/page-1"?

Comment: That's because the same component is being used, so only a re-render will happen.

Comment: How to make it remount instead? I'm fetching data from an API and I want to let users know that the app is getting data and hasn't crashed - thus the loading screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same component is being used, so only a re-render will happen. The constructor will not be called again.

For these circumstances, I recommend trying into the `componentWillRecieveProps` and check to see if the `pagename` param is changing:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(this.props.match.params.pagename !== nextProps.match.params.pagename) {
        this.setState({ loading: true });
        setTimeout(...);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the same Component is being loaded, you could try this i have not tested this code but i think this would work

```
Page extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
 super(props);

 this.state = { loading: true };
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
 this.setState({ loading: true });
 setTimeout(() => {
   this.setState({ loading: false });
 }, 1000);
}

render() {
  return this.state.loading ? (
     <h1>Loading...</h1>
     ) : (
     <h1>{this.props.match.params.pagename}</h1>
  );
 }
}
```